# Creating an AMI is not copying sshd file settings

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have user and password auth configured for my instances but every one I launch I have to do this at startup:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo sed -i 's/PasswordAuthentication no/PasswordAuthentication yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo service sshd restart
```

Is there a reason creating an image from an existing instance isn't copying that file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344390/how-do-i-get-aws-ec2-to-not-reset-my-sshd-config-file

Comment: @ceejayoz perfect

Answer (score 0):

Question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344390/how-do-i-get-aws-ec2-to-not-reset-my-sshd-config-file

Configuration is in the /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg file